# What does this mean: The exact controller to render is passed as a constructor argument to this listener - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

On [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#handling-exceptions-the-kernel-exception-event) it says:

> 3) A controller is executed and passed the flattened exception. The exact controller to render is passed as a constructor argument to this listener. This controller will return the final Response for this error page.

I need to do this:

> The exact controller to render is passed as a constructor argument to this listener

What does this mean? The docs have no examples.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Context would be useful

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the link

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to see the code of [ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php). As you can see constructor takes as  argument $controller. It is a string that indicates which controller will be used on subrequest.
By default it is a

```
Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::showAction
```

And this controller will return the final Response for this error exception